# Get every value from a custom attribute textbox

Tags: magento

I am wondering if there is any way to wrap **every line** of a textbox into a div.

I created a extension that gets the custom textbox youtube in a block and returns it.

For example:

The custom textbox youtube contains (every iframe one a new line):

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="URL_1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="URL_2" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

when i get the content of the custom field

```
return $_product->getYoutube();
```

i want it to output:

```
<div class"youtube"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="URL_1"...</div>
<div class"youtube"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="URL_1"...</div>
```

Hope somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_product->getYoutube() just returns string, so you can just use php function [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace). 
Try something like that:

```
$content = $_product->getYoutube();
//for opening tag
$content = str_replace("<iframe", '<div class="youtube"><iframe', $content);
//for closing tag
$content = str_replace("</iframe>", '</iframe></div>', $content);
return $content;
```